# Json.net 6.0.6 not apply MetadataType to EF dynamicproxy objects

Tags: entity-framework, json.net

I use MetadataType to apply attributes such as JsonIgnore to Entity Framework Objects like this

```
[MetadataType(typeof(FooMetadata))]
public partial class Foo
{
    private class FooMetadata
    {
        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual Bar Bar { get; set; }
    }
}
```

It works fine before json.net 6.0.6, now I need to set ProxyCreationEnabled to false to have it work again. Hope there will be a fix for this.

Comment: I wrote a demo project, please download here:
http://1drv.ms/1CtViPW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 6.0.8 fixed this issue.
Get it here: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/6.0.8